# How to use custom icons inside custom button class

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I have a problem. I created custom icons with [FlutterIcon](https://www.fluttericon.com/).
This is what I got from FlutterIcon and also a `.ttf`-file:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class CustomIcons {
  CustomIcons._();

  static const _kFontFam = 'CustomIcons';
  static const String? _kFontPkg = null;

  static const IconData construction = IconData(0xe841, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
}
```

The problem is that I have a custom button class. Inside this custom button class I would like to show the custom icon. The var `label!.uiIcon` consist something like `star` when I change it to for example a custom icon I get an error. So how can I use my CustomIcons inside the custom button class?

The code complies correctly if I have open the app on the phone it shows:

`Bad state: No element. See also ...`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:my_package/custom_icons_icons.dart';

import '../utils/definitions.dart';
import 'icons.dart';
import '../model/label.dart';

class LabelButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Label? label;
  final VoidStringCallback? process;

  LabelButton({required this.label, required this.process, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (label != null) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          child: Material(
            child: InkWell(
              highlightColor: Color(0xFF00D3F8).withOpacity(0.3),
              splashColor: Color(0xFFB20DD3).withOpacity(0.3),
              onTap: () {
                process!(label!.name);
                HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
              },
              child: Ink(
                width: 100, // Breite anpassen
                height: 120, // Höhe anpassen
                //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFB6B6B6),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(iconList
                        .firstWhere((element) => element.name == label!.uiIcon)
                        .icon,
                      size: 80,),
                    Icon(CustomIcons.construction,
                      size: 80,),

                    Text(label!.categoryName,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF696969),
                            //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          )),
                    Text(label!.name,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      )), // Text unter dem Icon
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )

        )

      );
    }
    else {
      return Container();
    }


  }

  const LabelButton._(this.label, this.process, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  static LabelButton createBlank() {
    return const LabelButton._(null, null);
  }
}
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Category {
  String name;
  IconData icon;

  Category(this.name, this.icon);
}

List<Category> iconList = [
  Category("construction", Icons.man),
  Category("bicycle", Icons.pedal_bike),
  Category("motorcycle", Icons.motorcycle),
  Category("car", Icons.car_rental),
  Category("train", Icons.train),
  Category("stroller", Icons.stroller),
  Category("rain", Icons.water_drop),
  Category("snow", Icons.snowing),
  Category("fog", Icons.foggy),
  Category("street_light", Icons.traffic),
  Category("street_sign", Icons.signpost),
  Category("star", Icons.star)
];
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I got `Bad state: No element.`

Comment: Did you include the ttf in your project, and did you also add it to the `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Yes, with `CustomIcons.construction,` I can see the icon. 
But when I do the following `Icon(CustomIcons.label!.uiIcon`, I got the error... :/

Comment: Why would you think that would work? `CustomIcons` doesn't have a `label` property. Maybe you just want it to the category list? Then just add to the `iconList` `Category("custom", CustomIcons.construction)` for example

Comment: @Ivo ahh I see, thanks for hint! Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: Like I wrote it. You have that `iconList` there. Where you have `Category("star", Icons.star)` you just insert on the line under it `Category("custom", CustomIcons.construction)` and then when you want that icon you use `label!.uiIcon` "custom". Or maybe I misunderstand what you try to do